# OpenCV Haar Training error

Tags: windows, opencv, haar-classifier

Hi i'm working on creating my own classifier to detect an object underwater. Everything is working fine until the final step when i try to generate an XML file using the opencv_haartraining i don't get an error but the program seems to exit without doing anything.
any help?
here is a link with an image for what is happening:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmz9zwb7351t7e1/error.png?dl=0

Comment: Did you check that the negative samples are all found as specified by the negative sample input file ??

Comment: yes all the negative pictures are there

Comment: Did you make sure the height and width settings for haar training are set just like you have for the positive samples ??

Comment: there is other error i just found when i try to get a sample from my vec file i get this error https://www.dropbox.com/s/77rcb48sb6rf11k/sample%20error.png?dl=0

Comment: well the height and width are set correctly

Comment: i have this new error when i run the haartraining https://www.dropbox.com/s/jhmp4e8l5hzc6ai/newerror.png?dl=0

Comment: This is probably because you haven't set your memory correctly in the training options. When starting the training, give it smaller memory (according to your machine's RAM size).

Comment: Aha i tried to use 250 for the mem option i still get the same error

Comment: I have new error you can see it here https://www.dropbox.com/s/piapgqujmil7b5m/latest%20error.png?dl=0